# All applications stop working after uninstall of hosting bundle 2.2.8

Tags: .net-core, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I have tried to clean up a bit from old core versions on a server (Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 8). When I uninstalled the .NET Core Runtime & Hosting Bundles version 2.2.8 (uninstalled with dotnet-core-uninstall) all applications on the server stops working. None of the applications uses Core 2.2, all is Core 3.1 and .Net5.

I have a almost identical server with the same applications and there the applications still works after uninstalling the 2.2.8 Hosting Bundle.

I'm guessing there is something on the server that depends on version 2.2.8, but what?

Anyone who has any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what the uninstallation steps did to break your server, but rerun .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 Hosting Bundle installers should bring things back I think.

Comment: Have you tried to restart IIS or reboot server? Maybe this can make application work again.

Comment: Hi. I reinstalled 3.1, and restarted the IIS. I will try and also reinstall .NET 5 and also restart the server

Answer (score 1):

Came across this today and found a fix. At least in our case, we had to completely uninstall all .net core hosting bundles and runtimes. Rebooted the server, then reinstalled only .net 5 and 6, and boom it worked. Was having the exact same problem with 2.2.8

Comment: something is problematic with .net core 2

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same thing:  Uninstalled dot net 2.2.8, and most other iis-based web apps failed to launch, even after server restart. I then proceeded to uninstall the only other hosting bundle (7.0.10), restart, re-install of hosting bundle 7.0.10, and all seems proper.